# How to simplify multiple equals checks in if condition?

Tags: kotlin

How can I do this easier with Kotlin?

```
if (translation.equals(TRANSLATION_X) || 
    translation.equals(TRANSLATION_Y) || 
    translation.equals(TRANSLATION_Z)
) {
    return
} else {
    translation = TRANSLATION_X
}
```

Answer (score 32):

First, you can use the [structural equality operator `==`](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/equality.html#structural-equality), which is translated to the `.equals(...)` calls automatically: `translation == TRANSLATION_X` instead of `translation.equals(TRANSLATION_X)`.

Then, you can use the [`when` statement](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/control-flow.html#when-expression):

```
when (translation) {
    TRANSLATION_X, TRANSLATION_Y, TRANSLATION_Z -> return
    else -> translation = TRANSLATION_X
}
```

Answer (score 20):

Another alternative that may be more efficient than a `when` expression is to use a `Set`:

```
val options = setOf(TRANSLATION_X, TRANSLATION_Y, TRANSLATION_Z)

if (translation in options) return
else translation = TRANSLATION_X
```

Comment: I believe a lookup in a three-items set is faster  either when it is an `EnumSet` or when the `equals` check is quite expensive while `hashCode` calculation is not. Otherwise, especially with default `equals` implementation (i.e. identity equals) and primitives, a set will hardly give any performance improvement.

Comment: This depends on a lot of things. But sure, might not be more efficient, that's why I said `may be more efficient`.

Answer (score 6):

A when statement seems appropriated in this situation :

```
val translation = when( translation ) {
    TRANSLATION_X -> translation
    TRANSLATION_Y -> translation
    TRANSLATION_Z -> translation
    else TRANSLATION_X
}
```

I think you can also group the three similar cases in one sentence like this :

```
val translation = when( translation ) {
    TRANSLATION_X, TRANSLATION_Y, TRANSLATION_Z -> translation
    else TRANSLATION_X
}
```

Comment: Note: this code does not preserve the semantics of the original piece of code in the question: `val translation = ...` will just shadow the `translation` from the outer scope (or won't compile if that's a local variable), and `translation` will not be reassigned.